# How to upload photo in a folder and save path in the database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Im trying to add an image to folder and path to the database but i've tried to figure out how to go about this but nothing is working. please help.
Here's my controller

```
function index()
{           
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required|trim|xss_clean');           
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('photo', 'photo', 'required|trim|xss_clean');                             
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|trim|xss_clean');                   

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error">', '</span>');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // validation hasn't been passed
    {
        $this->load->view('registration');
    }
    else // passed validation proceed to post success logic
    {
        // build array for the model

        $form_data = array(
                        'username' => set_value('username'),
                        'photo' => set_value('photo'),
                        'password' => set_value('password')                  
                    );

        // run insert model to write data to db

        if ($this->kint_model->SaveForm($form_data) == TRUE) // the information has therefore been successfully saved in the db
        {
            redirect('user_registration/success');   // or whatever logic needs to occur
        }
        else
        {
        echo 'An error occurred saving your information. Please try again later';
        // Or whatever error handling is necessary
        }
    }
}
function success()
{
        echo 'User registered successfully';
}
```

Here's my model

```
class Kint_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function SaveForm($form_data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('users', $form_data);

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

And here's my view

```
<?php // Change the css classes to suit your needs    

$attributes = array('class' => '', 'id' => '');
echo form_open('user_registration', $attributes); ?>

<p>
        <label for="username">username <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
        <br /><input id="username" type="text" name="username"  value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <label for="photo">photo <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('photo'); ?>
        <br /><input id="photo" type="text" name="photo"  value="<?php echo set_value('photo'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <label for="password">password <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
        <br /><input id="password" type="text" name="password"  value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit'); ?>
</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
function index()
{           
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required|trim|xss_clean');                        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|trim|xss_clean');                   

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error">', '</span>');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // validation hasn't been passed
    {
        $this->load->view('registration');
    }
    else 
    {

        $form_data = array(
                        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                        'photo' => '',
                        'password' => $this->input->post('password')      
                    );


            $UploadPreferences = array(
               'upload_path'   => './uploads/fullsize',
             'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
                'encrypt_name'  => TRUE
              );

         $this->upload->initialize($UploadPreferences);
            $this->upload->do_upload('photo');

            $photoInfo = $this->upload->data();

            $form_data['photo'] = $photoInfo['full_path'];
        if ($this->kint_model->SaveForm($form_data) == TRUE) // the information has therefore been successfully saved in the db
        {
            redirect('user_registration/success');   // or whatever logic needs to occur
        }
        else
        {
        echo 'An error occurred saving your information. Please try again later';
        // Or whatever error handling is necessary
        }
    }
}
function success()
{
        echo 'User registered successfully';
}
```

View:

```
    <?php // Change the css classes to suit your needs    

$attributes = array('class' => '', 'id' => '');
echo form_open('user_registration', $attributes); ?>

<p>
        <label for="username">username <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
        <br /><input id="username" type="text" name="username"  value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <label for="photo">photo <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('photo'); ?>
        <br /><input type="file" name="photo" multiple="multiple" />
</p>

<p>
        <label for="password">password <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
        <br /><input id="password" type="text" name="password"  value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit'); ?>
</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

It is untested.

Read also:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Do : `var_dump($this->upload->data());` also.

Comment: Im having a huge problem in that the code doesn't save the image path to the database but instead it saves  ./uploads/fullsize/   as the path name to the database and also no image is uploaded to the upload folder. Im not much experienced in codeigniter. Any help will be appreciated.